# Flutter: Remove ChangeNotifier Boilerplate `notifyListeners()`

Tags: flutter, annotations, boilerplate

Is there something like @annotation to remove the boilerplate when creating a model class that extend `ChangeNotifier`?

Boilerplate

```
class MyModel extends ChangeNotifier{
  bool _isLoading = true;

  bool get isLoading => _isLoading;

  set isLoading(bool value) {
    _isLoading = value;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

Using something like @annotation

```
class MyModel extends ChangeNotifier{
  @Notify
  bool _isLoading = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try Get for your state management: https://pub.dev/packages/get

Reactive programming with Get is as easy as using setState.

First you can create a new controller:

```
import 'package:get/get.dart';

class FormController extends GetxController {
  FormController();

  Rx<bool> _isLoading = false.obs;
  set setLoading(value) => this._isLoading.value = value;
  bool get loading => this._isLoading.value;
}
```

And in the UI, when you want to show that value and update the screen whenever the values changes, simply do this:

```
Obx(
                    () => formController.loading
                        ? Center(
                            child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                          )
                        : ElevatedButton(
                            onPressed: formController.googleLoading ||
                                    formController.anonymousLoading
                                ? null
                                : () async {
                                    formController.setLoading = true;
                                    if (_formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
                                      await userController
                                          .loginWithEmailAndPassword(
                                              formController.email,
                                              formController.password);
                                    }
                                    formController.setLoading = false;
                                  },
                            child: Text('login'.tr),
                          ),
                  ),
```

See an more in-depth explanation of state management [here](https://github.com/jonataslaw/getx/blob/master/documentation/en_US/state_management.md). There you will see more examples and also the difference between the simple state manager and the reactive state manager

You will get a good idea of GetX power.

Comment: No, I just want to use Provider for the state management